# CodeIgniter difference in result_array when using while or foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function in my model:

```
public function get_current_knowledge($account_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM knowledge WHERE account_id = ?', array($account_id));

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I used to access it like this:

```
while ($record = $this->synchronization_model->get_current_knowledge($account['id'])) {
    print_r($record);
}
```

But strangely, my page would timeout probably because the while results in a neverending loop or something? But why is the question.

I noticed that foreach does work. But essentially this should return the same as while right?
When accessing it like this, using foreach:

```
foreach ($this->synchronization_model->get_current_knowledge($account['id']) as $row)
{
     print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while()` loop runs for as long as whatever is inside the parentheses is truthy.

You're assigning the value of `$this->synchronization_model->get_current_knowledge($account['id'])` to the variable `$record` every time the loop runs. Of course, the variable has a value (since you're assigning it), and so its always truthy. That's where you get your infinite loop.

Comment: But I used the while loop before I converted this code to codeigniter style. Like, while($record = pg_fetch_array(..) and in that time it used too work. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I think it would break out of the loop if `$record` was assigned a false value. It's hard for me to get the bigger picture of how your code previously behaved.

Comment: Yeah, I looked up pg_fetch_array on PHP.net. It returns false when the last row is returned. Apparently this does not happen when using the code I'm know using. Deciedd to switch to foreach where I previously used while. That should yield the same results right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should do. You're welcome! Remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)